# Como fazer um menu em Console no Python

Tags: python

Necessito fazer um menu no console em Python, porém o mesmo deve ser acionado através de letras e não números, por exemplo:

```
def menu():
print('''
        MENU:

        [C] - Cadastrar novo voto
        [R] - Ver Resultado
        [S] - Sair
    ''')
str(input('Escolha uma opção: '))
```

Então quando a pessoa digitar `c` no teclado ela acessa cadastrar novo voto. Consigo fazer através de números porém o exercício pede que seja desta maneira.

Este é o código do programa que fiz:

```
def menu():
    print('''
            MENU:

            [C] - Cadastrar novo voto
            [R] - Ver Resultado
            [S] - Sair
        ''')
    str(input('Escolha uma opção: '))

cadastrarVoto = "c"
verResultado =  "r"
sair = "s"

def porcentagem (n, t):
    return (n/t)*100


menu()
if(cadastrarVoto):
    while (cadastrarVoto):
        n = int(input("Digite o número de um jogador para cadastrar um voto  (0 = Voltar ao menu): "))
        if (n != 0):
            votos = 23 * [0.0]
            total = 0

            while (n != 0):
                if (n < 0 or n > 23):
                    print("Informe um valor entre 1 e 23 ou 0 para sair!")
                else:
                    votos[n - 1] += 1
                    total += 1
                    n = int(input("Digite o número de um jogador para cadastrar um novo voto (0 = Voltar ao menu): "))
        if (n == 0):
            menu()

if (verResultado):
    print("Resultado da votação:")

    print("Foram computados %de votos." % (total))

    print("Jogador / Votos / Porcentagem")

    i = 0
    melhor = 0
    melhorPorcentagem = porcentagem(votos[0], total)

    while i < 23:
        porcentagemAtual = porcentagem(votos[i], total)
        print("%d / %d / %.1f" % (i + 1, votos[i], porcentagemAtual))
        if (porcentagemAtual > melhorPorcentagem):
            melhor = i
            melhorPorcentagem = porcentagemAtual
        i += 1

    print("O melhor jogador foi o número %d, com %d votos, correspondendo a %.1f porcento do total de votos" % (
    melhor + 1, votos[melhor], melhorPorcentagem))

if (sair):
    print ('Programa Finalizado')
```

Comment: Você está pedindo ao usuário que opção ele quer e está jogando fora. Na linha 9 dentro da função `menu`, ao invés de `str(input('Escolha uma opção: '))` você pode guardar em uma variável ou mesmo retornar a opção escolhida. Ex.: `return str(input('Escolha uma opção: '))`

Answer (score 2):

A função `input()` pede ao usuário para digitar algo, e, em seguida, retorna uma string contendo o que foi digitado pelo usuário. No caso, você está chamando a função aqui:

```
str(input('Escolha uma opção: '))
```

Ao invés de armazenar a opção escolhida pelo usuário, você está chamando a função `str()` para converter o resultado em string, e, em seguida, descartando o resultado. Seja lá o que o usuário digite, está sendo perdido, pois não é feito nada com esse resultado da função.

Uma forma comum de se trabalhar é armazenar o resultado em uma variável:

```
opcao_escolhida = str(input('Escolha uma opção: '))
```

Porém, como variáveis normalmente são locais ao escopo de uma função, e você está rodando o `input()` dentro da função `menu()`, essa variável `opcao_escolhida` só existiria dentro dessa função. Neste caso, para não ter que colocar toda a lógica de tratamento dentro da função junto, talvez seja melhor usar o `return` que permite que as funções retornem valores:

```
return str(input('Escolha uma opção: '))
```

Assim, o valor digitado será retornado para quem chamou a função. Basta mudar a sua chamada de função:

```
menu()
```

para:

```
opcao_escolhida = menu()
```

Após essas modificações, será possível usar essa variável para verificar a opcão digitada:

```
if opcao_escolhida == 'c':
    # ... Aqui entra o código para cadastro de voto ...
```

Answer (score -3):

RODANDO...

def menu():
print('''
MENU:

```
        [C] - Cadastrar novo voto
        [R] - Ver Resultado
        [S] - Sair
    ''')
```

menu()
opcao_escolhida = str(input("Escolha a opção: "))

cadastrarVoto = "c"
verResultado =  "r"
sair = "s"
votos = 0
total = 0

def porcentagem (n, t):
return (n/t)*100

if(opcao_escolhida == "c"):
n = int(input("Digite o número de um jogador para cadastrar um voto  (0 = Voltar ao menu): "))
if (n >= 0):
votos = 23 * [0.0]
total = 0

while (n != 0):
if (n < 0 or n > 23):
print("Informe um valor entre 1 e 23 ou 0 para sair!")
else: (n > 0)
n = int(input("Digite o número de um jogador para cadastrar um novo voto (0 = Voltar ao menu): "))
votos[n - 1] += 1
total += 1
if(n == 0):
menu()
opcao_escolhida == 0
opcao_escolhida = str(input("Escolha a opção: "))
""" opcao_escolhida = str(input("Escolha a opção: "))"""
if (opcao_escolhida == "r"):
print("Resultado da votação:")

```
print("Foram computados de votos."%[total])

print("Jogador / Votos / Porcentagem")

i = 0
melhor = 0
melhorPorcentagem = porcentagem(votos[0], total)

while i < 23:
    porcentagemAtual = porcentagem(votos[i], total)
    print("%d / %d / %.1f" % (i + 1, votos[i], porcentagemAtual))
    if (porcentagemAtual > melhorPorcentagem):
        melhor = i
        melhorPorcentagem = porcentagemAtual
    i += 1

print("O melhor jogador foi o número %d, com %d votos, correspondendo a %.1f porcento do total de votos" % (
melhor + 1, votos[melhor], melhorPorcentagem))
```

if (opcao_escolhida == "s"):
print ('Programa Finalizado')

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).