# Juntar 2 Programas - Python (3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Criei 2 programas separadamente para converter Reais em Dólares e outro para converter Dólares em reais, o que eu gostaria de fazer é criar uma espécie de menu ou input, onde estaria escrito:

"Digite 1 para converter Reais em Dólares ou 2 para converter Dólares em reais" quando o usuário digitar 1, o programa inicia a variável que trabalha essa conversão, se digitar 2, outra variável é chamada na tela do usuário.

Segue abaixo os 2 programas:

```
#------------Reais P/ Dolar------------------------

Reais = float (input("Quantos reais? R$: "))

Cotação = float (input("Cotação de hoje é? "))

conversão = Reais/Cotação

print("Você possui US$" , ("%.2f" % conversão))

#-----------Dolar P/ Reais-------------------------

Dolar = float(input("Quantos Dolares? US$: "))

Cotação = float(input("Cotação de hoje é? "))

Conversão = Cotação*Dolar

print("Você possui: R$", ("%.2f" % Conversão))
```

Comment: Você já conhece o conceito de função?

Comment: A [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349166/110782) desta pergunta irá te ajudar: [Como fazer um menu em Console no Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349163/como-fazer-um-menu-em-console-no-python)

Answer (score 3):

É uma ideia boa, e podes aplicar alguns conceitos de programação como a criação de funções para cada uma das tuas conversões [Aprender sobre funções](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions). 
Exemplo:

```
def reaisParaDolar(reais, cotacao):
    conversao = reais / cotacao
    return conversao
```

De seguida para construir o teu menu podes fazer algo deste tipo:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Reais = float (input("Quantos reais? R$: "))
    Cotação = float (input("Cotação de hoje é? "))

    operacao = int(input('1 - Reais para Dolar; 2 - Dolar para Reais')

    if operacao == 1:
        resultado = reaisParaDollar(Reais, Cotação)
        print("Você possui US$" , ("%.2f" % conversão))
    elif operacao == 2:
        resultado = dolarParaReais(Reais, Cotação)
        print("Você possui: R$", ("%.2f" % Conversão))
    else:
        print("Operação Inválida")
```

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão seria primeiro dividir seus programas em duas funções:

```py
def reaispdolar () :
    Reais = float (input("Quantos reais? R$: "))
    Cotação = float (input("Cotação de hoje é? "))
    conversão = Reais/Cotação
    print("Você possui US$" , ("%.2f" % conversão))
    return

def dolarpreais () :
    Dolar = float(input("Quantos Dolares? US$: "))
    Cotação = float(input("Cotação de hoje é? "))
    Conversão = Cotação*Dolar
    print("Você possui: R$", ("%.2f" % Conversão))
    return
```

Depois criar o menu utilizando print, input e if/else:

```py
print("O que você deseja fazer?")
print("1 - Converter reais para dólares")
print("2 - Converter dólares para reais")
menu = input("Digite a opção desejada\n")
if menu == "1" :
    reaispdolar()
elif menu == "2" :
    dolarpreais()
else :
    print("Você digitou algo errado, tente novamente")
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma variável para as opções, pedindo o input do usuário, depois teste a opção dentro de um “if” e coloque o primeiro programa, depois um “elif” com o segundo, e pode colocar um “else” que devolva “opção não válida” como são apenas duas opções é uma forma simples de resolver .

```
opcoes = int(input(("Digite 1 para conversoes de reais para dolar\nDigite 2 para conversoes de dolar para real:\n\n")))

if opcoes == 1:
    Reais = float(input("Quantos reais? R$: "))

    Cotação = float(input("Cotação de hoje é? "))

    conversão = Reais / Cotação

    print("Você possui US$", ("%.2f" % conversão))

elif opcoes == 2:
    Dolar = float(input("Quantos Dolares? US$: "))

    Cotação = float(input("Cotação de hoje é? "))

    Conversão = Cotação*Dolar

    print("Você possui: R$", ("%.2f" % Conversão))
else:
    print("Opção Invalida!")
```

Comment: Pedro, desenvolva sua resposta e coloque sua explicação junto com o código, assim ficará melhor para visualização